# When a Wild Shape'd druid uses his Attack Modifier, does the bonus from Potency runes work?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, druid, attack-roll, shapeshifting

When a druid uses [Wild Shape](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=481) they can choose to use his own attack modifier +2 instead of the the form's default one.

Does the attack modified include the bonus from the potency rune on the weapon wielded when he shapeshifted or is it lost because all his equipment is "absorbed", and the rune sort of activates when the weapon is *actually* wielded?

Comment: Are you interested in just weapons with potency runes, or also other items like _[handwraps of mighty blows](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=441)_ with potency runes?

Comment: yes @brandon, i would like to understand how they work too

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Yes... as long as you mean Handwraps of Mighty Blows (or similar)

The proviso "When you choose to use your own attack modifier while polymorphed instead of the form's default attack modifier, you gain a +2 status bonus to your attack rolls." is referring to a line in all (or at least most) of the *[type] form* spells:

> **If your unarmed attack bonus** is higher, you can use it instead.

Your unarmed attack modifier is still affected by your Potency runes and similar effects on Handwraps of Mighty Blows, so that value should be included when determining if you use "your attack modifier"*

*It's unclear whether you should include the +2 status bonus 'before' determining if you use your attack modifier or the battle forms (e.g. if your attack modifier is 1 lower than provided by the *form*), but logic says that you should assess all modifiers to either case and use the higher value.

Answer (score 3):

### Short answer: no

As a [battle form](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=127) (emphasis mine):

> If you take on a battle form with a polymorph spell, the special statistics can be adjusted only by circumstance bonuses, status bonuses, and penalties. Unless otherwise noted, the battle form prevents you from casting spells, speaking, and using most manipulate actions that require hands. (If there's doubt about whether you can use an action, the GM decides.) Your gear is absorbed into you; **the constant abilities of your gear still function, but you can't activate any items**.

So it seems like this +2 would count as a "constant ability" and still function, right?

Well, yes, but no.

[Weapon potency](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=281) :

> Magical enhancements make this weapon strike true. Attack rolls **with this weapon** gain a +1 item bonus, and the weapon can be etched with one property rune.

So this ability of granting +1 item bonus to attacks with this weapon still "function", but it still only applies on attacks "with this weapon", which you are not doing when polymorphed.

That said if you managed somehow to wield a +1 potency weapon while in battle form its +1 would work fine (as long as you are using your own attack modifier because "the special statistics can be adjusted only by circumstance bonuses, status bonuses, and penalties").

Comment: The item in quesiton would be Handwraps of Mighty Blows, which apply to unarmed attacks. All (afaik) spells that provide a Battle Form with attacks include "If your unarmed attack bonus is higher, you can use it instead. "

Comment: Well, the question was about a weapon, which the handwraps are not. I think my answer it the correct one to the actual question being asked and the issue is that the OP didn't ask the question they needed. Anyway, that's great that you managed to help them!